# Android Camera Example

Tags: java, android, camera

I am working on android camera application, and I found a code to start with:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/

But I faced two problems that I couldn't understand. The first one is in this part:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    myContext = this;
    initialize();
}
```

In fact, I didn't understand what is initialize() and what the purpose of it? I searched for it but I didn't find anything!

The second problem is in this part:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
    if (mCamera == null) {

        //if the front facing camera does not exist

        if (findFrontFacingCamera()  1) {

            //release the old camera instance

            //switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

            releaseCamera();
            chooseCamera();

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
};
```

I didn't understand this expression: `if (findFrontFacingCamera()  1).`  Because `findFrontFacingCamera()` is not `boolean` and there is problem in 1!

Answer (score 1):

There are typos and omissions in the tutorial. The onResume per downloaded project is

```
super.onResume();
    if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
    if (mCamera == null) {
        if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
        mPicture = getPictureCallback();
        mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }
```

BTW, the initialize method is not included in the tutorial either.  The code is as follows:

```
public void initialize() {
    cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
    cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

    capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(captureListener);

    switchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ChangeCamera);
    switchCamera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initialize()
```

makes sure that your camera is initialized

> didn't understand this expression: if (findFrontFacingCamera() 1).
>   Because findFrontFacingCamera() is not boolean and there is problem in
>   1!

In this case, when you try to find camera (usually there are 2 cameras on device, but in some cases there is just rear or just front camera)
So the "1" flag means that you want to select second camera, while "0" will select the first (usually rear) camera

Comment: But when I write initialize(), eclipse says it is undefined and gives error!

Answer (score 0):

i believe its a typo?? from the comment line,

```
//if the front facing camera does not exist
```

before the if condition, i could see the following change is required.
change the line

```
if (findFrontFacingCamera() 1)
```

to

```
if (findFrontFacingCamera()== -1)
```

as i can see in the example, this is a method that returns id of the camera .

Note that for a front facing camera id = 1 and for a back cam , its 0.